# Elegantly create a variable-size "2D-pointer" list in runtime-stack, using macros

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c-preprocessor, c99, callstack

This is somewhat of both a best-practise question, and a technical one, and has a bit of context.

The TL-DR: I want to use a single-line-definition macro to create anonymous variable-sized arrays.

Note in my below question, I cannot use `gcc` extensions - I can only take vanilla `C99` for granted.

## Context

In my project (a simulation software used by external users), there are several structs with 2D arrays

```
typedef struct ComplexMatrix2
{
    double real[2][2];
    double imag[2][2];
} ComplexMatrix2;

typedef struct ComplexMatrix4
{
    double real[4][4];
    double imag[4][4];
} ComplexMatrix4;

typedef struct ComplexMatrixN 
{
    int n;
    double** real;
    double** imag;
} ComplexMatrixN;
```

As you can see, while `ComplexMatrix` `2` and `4` have fixed-size 2D arrays, `ComplexMatrixN` is variable size and so its `real` and `imag` fields are pointers. This is motivated by `ComplexMatrix` `2` and `4` being significantly more commonly used and so need to be efficiently/concisely created. Here's some example usage:

```
// passing compound literal in-line, kept in stack
myfunc2( (ComplexMatrix2) {.real={{1,2},{3,4}}, .imag={{0}}} );
```

```
// initialising in stack
ComplexMatrix4 m4 = {
    .real = {{1,2,3,4},
             {5,6,7,8},
             {9,10,11,12},
             {13,14,15,16}},
    .imag = {{0}}};
myfunc4( m );
```

```
// no initialisation, not in-line, created in heap
ComplexMatrixN m8 = createComplexMatrixN(8);

for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
        m16.real[i][j] = 1;

myfuncN(m8);

destroyComplexMatrixN(m8);
```

It's quite unfortunate that, although more rarely used, `ComplexMatrixN` has to be dynamically created, cannot be initialised and cannot be created/passed in-line.

Note that users are extremely unlikely to make large `ComplexMatrixN`, e.g. larger than `numQubits=6`. It is therefore safe to keep `ComplexMatrixN` in the stack (if possible), and ok to bound the ability to do so.

## Task

I wish to enable the user to elegantly create `ComplexMatrixN` in the stack if desired. That is, the `.real` and `.imag` fields are arrays in the stack, though which resolve to `double**`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
// internal code
ComplexMatrixN bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN(
    int n, double re[][n], double im[][n], 
    double** reStorage, double** imStorage)
{
    ComplexMatrixN m;
    m.n = n;
    m.real = reStorage;
    m.imag = imStorage;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        m.real[i] = re[i];
        m.imag[i] = im[i];
    }
    return m;
}
```

```
// user code
ComplexMatrixN m2 = bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN(
    2, 
    // initialising values
    (double[][2]) {{1,2},{3,4}}, 
    (double[2][2]) {{0}},
    // stack-space for array of pointers
    (double*[2]) {}, 
    (double*[2]) {}
);

myfuncN(m2);
```

The calling code in `main` is allocating 4 arrays in the stack, and `bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN` is merely populating them and binding them to a `ComplexMatrixN` instance. 
The call to `bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN` can even be made inside the argument to `myfuncN` so that the `ComplexMatrixN` isn't in scope!

Although this method allows initialisation, creation-in-stack, and inline creation, it has two drawbacks:

- since the arrays live in the calling scope, they'll dangle if the `ComplexMatrixN` is 'returned', unlike a dynmically created `ComplexMatrixN`. This is totally okay.
- the user has to verbosely passing `(double*[4]) {}, (double*[4]) {}` in order to create the additional arrays needed in-stack.

So I am wondering if, for a *variable* size `ComplexMatrixN`, I can use macros to supply `(double*[4]) {}, (double*[4]) {}` automatically. This would be a safe macro for users, since it is desirably one-line and doesn't add any new variables to the calling scope.

## An attempt

The most obvious way to do go about this for a *variable* size is not possible, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747089/allocate-variable-length-array-inline-function-call).

I.e. one might think we could simplfy define a macro

```
// internal code
#define createStackComplexMatrixN(num, re, im) ( \
    bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN( \
        num, re, im, \
        (double*[num]) {}, (double*[num]) {} \
    ) \
)
```

```
// user code
ComplexMatrixN m = createStackComplexMatrixN(
    1,
    (double[][2]) ({{1,2},{3,4}}), 
    (double[2][2]) ({{0}})
);
myfuncN(m);

// note user had to wrap array literals in brackets, else macro misintreprets #args
```

but this will invoke `error: compound literal has variable size`, because `(double[num]) {}` is illegal in C99.

The next obvious way to get around this limitation is to not attempt to initialise the arrays of pointers:

```
// internal code
#define createStackComplexMatrixN(num, re, im) ( { \
    double* reStorage_[num]; \
    double* imStorage_[num]; \
    bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN( \
        num, re, im, reStorage_, imStorage_) \
} )
```

```
// user code
ComplexMatrixN m = createStackComplexMatrixN(
    1,
    (double[][2]) ({{1,2},{3,4}}),
    (double[2][2]) ({{0}})
);
myfuncN(m);
```

which works in this example, but now...

- we undesirably add `reStorage_` and `imStorage_` to the calling scope
- the macro expands to **3** lines instead of **1**, so it now cannot be inlined! I.e.

```
myfuncN(
    createStackComplexMatrixN(1,
        (double[][2]) ({{1,2},{3,4}}),
        (double[2][2]) ({{0}}))
);
```

is now invalid (and note I cannot use the [Blocks extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)), which would fix this latter problem).

## An inelegant solution

We could get around the variable-size compound literal by just defining many macros for each size the user may want to create.

```
#define getCompMatr6(re, im) ( \
    bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN( \
        6, (double[6][6]) re, (double[6][6]) im, \
        (double*[6]) {}, (double*[6]) {} \
    ) \
)

#define getCompMatr8(re, im) ( \
    bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN( \
        8, (double[8][8]) re, (double[8][8]) im, \
        (double*[8]) {}, (double*[8) {} \
    ) \
)

...
```

```
// user code

myfuncN(
    getCompMatr6(
        ({{1,2,3,4,5,6}, 
         {9,8,7,6,5,4}, {0}}),
        ({{0}})));

myfuncN(
    getCompMatr8(
        ({{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, {0}}),
        ({{0}})));
```

This is relatively elegant for the end-user. However, in this example, they'll have to call different functions to initialise different sized `ComplexMatrixN` (though this isn't really something users would want to do automatically, so that's ok).

## A slightly more elegant solution

We can allow the user to instead pass a literal size of the `ComplexMatrixN`, to avoid any code duplication, and avoid cluttering the namespace!

```
// internal code
#define getCompMatrN(num, re, im) ( \
    bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN( \
        num, (double[num][num]) re, (double[num][num]) im, \
        (double*[num]) {}, (double*[um]) {} \
    ) \
)
```

```
// user code
myfuncN(
    getCompMatrN(
        8,
        ({{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, 
         {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2}, {0}}),
        ({{0}})));

myfuncN(
    getCompMatrN(
        16,
        ({{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}, {0}}),
        ({{0}})));
```

It would be invalid for the user to do

```
int var = 2;
getCompMatrN(var, ...)
```

since that will invoke the variable-length compound error.

However, this solution doesn't appear to work! It produces compile errors:

```sh
warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    ComplexMatrixN m = getCompMatrN(2, ({{1,2},{3,4}}), {{0}});
                                                    ^
note: expanded from macro 'getCompMatrN'
        num, (double[num][num]) re, (double[num][num]) im, \
                                     ^
error: expected ';' after expression
    ComplexMatrixN m = getCompMatrN(2, ({{1,2},{3,4}}), {{0}});
                                                       ^
note: expanded from macro 'getCompMatrN'
        num, (double[num][num]) re, (double[num][num]) im, \
                                     ^
warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    ComplexMatrixN m = getCompMatrN(2, ({{1,2},{3,4}}), {{0}});
                                                      ^
note: expanded from macro 'getCompMatrN'
        num, (double[num][num]) re, (double[num][num]) im, \
                                     ^
error: expected expression
    ComplexMatrixN m = getCompMatrN(2, ({{1,2},{3,4}}), {{0}});
                                                        ^
note: expanded from macro 'getCompMatrN'
        num, (double[num][num]) re, (double[num][num]) im, \
                                     ^
error: used type 'double [2][2]' where arithmetic or pointer type is
      required
    ComplexMatrixN m = getCompMatrN(2, ({{1,2},{3,4}}), {{0}});
                       ^                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: expanded from macro 'getCompMatrN'
        num, (double[num][num]) re, (double[num][num]) im, \
             ^
error: expected expression
note: expanded from macro 'getCompMatrN'
    ); \
       ^
```

Admittedly I don't understand the cause of these errors.

## My questions

- Is it possible to make the above example work? Is there a mistake in my macro definition, or is passing array literals like this just not possible?
- Are there any lurking dangers in exposing such a macro (if it worked like expected), despite it resolving to a single line without changing the calling scope, and not ending in a trailing `;`?
- Is there a much more sensible way to allow users to create `ComplexMatrixN` in the stack?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198905/discussion-on-question-by-anti-earth-elegantly-create-a-variable-size-2d-pointe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your last macro definition is that a compound literal has the syntax 
(§6.5.2):

```
( type-name ) { initializer-list }
( type-name ) { initializer-list , }
```

so that `(double[2][2])({{1,2},{3,4}})` is not a compound literal. `(double[2][2]){{1,2},{3,4}}` would be, but you need to play a little trick to feed that initializer as a macro argument, since without the parentheses, the comma won't be guarded. Here's one way to do it:

```
/* This macro is used to strip parentheses from an argument */
#define ID(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define getCompMatrN(num, re, im) ( \
    bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN( \
        num, (double[num][num]) ID re, (double[num][num]) ID im, \
        (double*[num]) {NULL}, (double*[num]) {NULL} \
    ) \
)

ComplexMatrixN m = 
    getCompMatrN(2, ({{1,2},{3,4}}), ({{0}}));
```

Note that with this formulation, the parentheses around the initializer list are *required* (see the change to the third argument of `getCompMatrN` in the last line).

I changed the last two arguments of `bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN` to `(double*[num]) {NULL}` because empty initializer lists are not valid C, even though some compilers might accept them.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements I've gleaned from the rather lengthy question are

- The objective is to provide a macro for initializers for objects of type `struct ComplexMatrixN`.
- The dimensions of the arrays to which the various pointers involved point must be accepted as one or more macro arguments.
- The solution should provide at least an option for wholly stack-based values.
- Only features of standard C99 may be used.

Although not expressed explicitly in the question, I presume the following characteristics are also required:

- The initialization macro can safely be used more than once in any given scope.
- None of the resulting initialization values alias each other.

Additionally, the question seems to say that it is desirable that:

- The resulting value remains valid and usable outside the context in which the initializer appears.

And I suppose it is also desirable that

- The macro is usable at file scope.

---

Unfortunately, the fact that `struct ComplexMatrixN` has pointer members presents some insurmountable barriers to achieving all of those at the same time.  Those members need to be initialized with valid pointer values that point to objects of suitable type, and if the pointed-to objects are declared in some block scope, as opposed to at file scope, then their lifetime ends when control passes out of the block.  This applies to the objects represented by compound literals just as it does to objects of scalar types, so

1. If the objects are initialized with pointers to stack-allocated objects then their values will not be safely usable outside the block in which the initializer appears.  Depending on the details, they might not even be safely usable inside that block.

If compound literals are going to be involved, then it is also important to understand that

2. The syntax for a compound literal does not permit the initializer part to be enclosed in parentheses.  This is the main source of the errors presented at the end of the question.  To be as clear as possible:

   ```
   // This contains a compound literal:
   double (*dp)[2] = (double[2][2]) {{1,2},{3,4}};

   // whereas THIS IS WRONG:
   double (*dp2)[2] = (double[2][2]) ({{1,2},{3,4}});
   ```

That means that generally you cannot pass the initializer part alone as a single macro argument, because without parentheses, the commas within will be taken as separating macro arguments.  This is a significant problem for all of the

I note also that

3. Any solution involving function calls in any way or involving value-assignment code outside the initializer is incompatible with use at file scope.  (Though the file-scope thing was my own addition, and so perhaps a bit of a straw man.)

How best to proceed depends on how general you require a solution to be, on how much assistance you want it to provide, and on how much macro magic you're willing to engage.

---

One alternative would be pretty much the very first attempt presented in the question.  You must correct the problem that empty initializers are not allowed, to yield this macro:

```
#define createStackComplexMatrixN(num, re, im) \
    bindArraysToStackComplexMatrixN( \
        num, re, im, \
        (double*[num]) {0}, (double*[num]) {0} \
    )
```

(I also removed the outer parentheses.)  The key with that is to invoke it correctly.  In particular, if the `re` and `im` arguments are expressed as compound literals, then they must each (in their entirety) be parenthesized:

```
ComplexMatrixN m = createStackComplexMatrixN(
    2,
    ((double[][2]) {{1,2},{3,4}}),
    ((double[2][2]) {{0}})
);
```

And of course, as already discussed, that cannot appear at file scope, and it is only good for the lifetime of the structures expressed via the compound literals.

---

It is conceivable that you could devise a solution based on variadic macros and macro pseudo-iteration that would be a bit easier for a user to write, or at least less open to inconsistencies, but that would be more of a project than I am prepared to undertake for an SO answer.

Comment: Ahh of course, if the macro arg is a literal, there's no issue with VLA initialisation! I imagine this is as good as it gets, thanks very much!